# How to write something with a mustache in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm trying to implement a website with AMP using Django technology, everything was okay just I want to make the change pagination without load the whole page so I need to use amp-list, the problem is when I start using it I get a problem.
I will explain a little bit about amp-list, to fetch data using amp-list we need to use some tag like the tags that exist on Django like {{#posts}} and {{slug}}, so the problem Django thinks those are variables.

a small example:

```
<amp-list width="auto" height="100" layout="fixed-height" src="myUrl" [src]="myUrl + pageNumber">
   <template type="amp-mustache">
       {{#posts}}
        <div>
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <p>{{content}}</p>
        </div>
        {{/posts}}
    </template>
</amp-list>
```

I have tried with some ways like put these in a variable and call it on the template but I get the same error. I wonder if there is a way that I can use those tags, I think there is something that let you write mustache in the Django template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of a [**`{% verbatim %}…{% endverbatim %}`** template block [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#verbatim) to disable interpreting tokens such as `{{` and `}}`.

If you thus do *not* want to interpret parts like `{{#posts}}`, `{{title}}`, etc. then you can surround this with a `verbatim` block:

```
{% verbatim %}
<amp-list width="auto" height="100" layout="fixed-height" src="myUrl" [src]="myUrl + pageNumber">
   <template type="amp-mustache">
       {{#posts}}
        <div>
            <h1>{{title}}</h1>
            <p>{{content}}</p>
        </div>
        {{/posts}}
    </template>
</amp-list>
{% endverbatim %}
```